# Is it okay to pass views into AndroidViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

I know passing views to ViewModel classes causes memory leaks but will it also cause memory leaks if I pass a view, let's say, a ProgressBar, in to an AndroidViewModel class like the following?

```
class MainActivityViewModel (application: Application, progressBar: ProgressBar): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    var name: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(docRef) {
        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        it.getString("string")
    }
}
```

I'm going to be using Data Binding to call `name` from my layout file like `android:text="@{viewModel.name]"`.

Will the above code cause a memory leak?

Comment: Don not pass anything related to context into viewmodel , that includes any type of view .

Comment: Passing a reference directy to a view model is a bad idea for several reasons. 1) Potential memory leaks if a hard refrence is kept in the view model 2) Separations of concern - if a view model is passed a View then it has access to the entire `View` object - it should be decoupled 3) the mvvm design pattern, the view model should only react to user events i.e onLoad(),` onSignIn(args ...)` or provide UI data. Of course this is your choice - but this is my immediate challenge to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will the above code cause a memory leak?

Yes, if the device undergoes a configuration change, such as the user rotating the screen.

In that case, your activity and its views will be destroyed and recreated, but your `MainActivityViewModel` will be retained and given to the new activity instance. But, it will still be holding a reference to `progressBar` from the old activity. This means:

- Android cannot garbage-collect the old activity, since your viewmodel is holding a reference to a `View` from that activity
- Calls to `progressBar` at best will have no effect and at worst will crash (e.g., `NullPointerException`), because that view is not being used by an active activity

Instead, have your code that is observing `name` (e.g. your activity or fragment) handle changing the visibility of this `progressBar`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course。
if you use databinding，
you can use a field to mark the view is gone，
just like the way you use the "name"